# Problem with bayesian implementation of a Time-lagged Linear Model in PyMC3

Tags: regression, time-series, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, lags

I am trying to build a GLM of a time-series y(t) with 2 predictor time series x1(t) and x2(t), where t is in days. But the second time-series influences y(t) with an unknown lag of l days. I was trying to model this in a Bayesian framework using PyMC3 in Python and fit the lag using the code below:

```
from pymc3 import *

import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

with Model() as model:
    # Define priors
    sigma = HalfCauchy('sigma', beta=10, testval=1.)
    intercept = Normal('Intercept', 0, sigma=20)
    x_coeff1 = Normal('x1', 0, sigma=20)
    x_coeff2 = Normal('x2', 0, sigma=20)
    lag = Poisson('lag',1)

    likelihood = Normal('y', mu=intercept + x_coeff1 * x1 + x_coeff2 * shift(x2,lag,cval=x2.mean()),
                        sigma=sigma, observed=y)

    trace = sample(3000, cores=4)
```

But it gives an error:

```
TypeError: argument must be symbolic vector, got 'lag'
TypeError: TensorType does not support iteration. Maybe you are using builtin.sum instead of theano.tensor.sum? (Maybe .max?)
```

When instead of setting a prior for lag, I give it a numerical value (say 4) with

```
likelihood = Normal('y', mu=intercept + x_coeff1 * x1 + x_coeff2 * shift(x2,4,cval=x2.mean()), sigma=sigma, observed=y)
```

it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong? How else can i fit the lag?

Comment: The current state is PyMC v5. I think that a modern answer should be in PyMC v5.

Answer (score 0):

The `shift` operator cannot be used with a tensor as lag. You should look for some other construction from `theano` or `pymc3.math` that does this for you. That's also what the error message is telling you, you are using a naive function (people often try to use `max` instead of `theano.max`) but that doesn't work.

As a simple way, you could instead use a for loop and sum the likelihood over all positions in the time series. This should make it easy to account for some interpolation problems you now solved with the `shift` function, using `cval`. Or perhaps some simple tensor slicing can be used.

Comment: can you explain how i could implement the summing the likelihood method? I am kind of new to this :)

Comment: Sum over all positions of time, and then the equation inside the sum (over t) is something like y_t ~ normal(a + b * x_(t-lag)) but then your full model.